# How do I get Next Car Game demo for Linux?

Tags: linux, wreckfest

I went to nextcargame.com to get the demo, and downloaded it. I set it to allow executing file as a program in properties, and opened it with Wine Windows Program Loader, and it installed fine.
When I start the game, it opens up fine and the title screen opens up for the game, but then it says: `The Program NextCarGameFreeTechnologyDemo.exe has encountered a serious problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvience.` And then it forces me to close.
I tried to uninstall it and reinstall it, but it said the same message.
Did I miss something, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This game is not available for Linux sorry, that's why it's crashing on start-up.

Answer (score -2):

You have to left click->Properties->Open With and choose a Format